# Hierarchical locking strategy of entries in a ConcurrentDictionary and the dictionary itself in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm forced to use a concurrent dictionary in my code, where the 'key' is a object and the 'value' is an int that represents a unique connection parameter to said object provided by a third party library. The connection parameter is stored, as when an event is thrown via the third party library, the unique key is one of the event arguments with which we can find the correct object to process further code on.

The issue I have is as follows:

- Occasionally, the concurrent dictionary needs to be updated with a refreshed list of objects that require processing.
- The individual objects require a lock during the processing, as the thrown events must be performed sequentially and not in parallel. (This has become a recent requirement as we're seeing that the tasks are sometimes being processes in parallel on different threads and getting an OptimisticConcurrencyException when saving to the database.)

Applying a lock to the individual objects within the dictionary is not a problem, but a new issue arises when I try to remove an object from the dictionary which is currently locked whilst refreshing the list.

I've tried to write a small console app that executes the problematic steps sequentially, the 'Monitor.Exit(key);' line throws the exception 'Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.'

```
class Program
{
    static ConcurrentDictionary<object, int> _handles = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, int>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object lockableKey = 'key';

        _handles.AddOrUpdate(lockableKey, 10, (oldkey, oldvalue) => 10);
        var key = _handles.Keys.FirstOrDefault(h => h == lockableKey);

        Console.WriteLine("key found, beginning to lock");
        Monitor.Enter(key);
        Console.WriteLine("key locked");

        ////Console.WriteLine("applying outer lock, hoping for code to stop executing");
        ////Monitor.Enter(_handles);

        Console.WriteLine("Removing key from dictionary");
        int dummy;
        _handles.TryRemove(lockableKey, out dummy);

        Console.WriteLine("Removing lock from object removed from dictionary");
        Monitor.Exit(key);
    }
```

So the question is, is there a way to apply a lock to the outer dictionary that acts like a master lock and waits for all child locks on objects within the dictionary to finish executing before refreshing the dictionary and continuing to process the incoming events?

Comment: Your code is confusing. You are using a `lockableKey` (set to "key", should be written with double quotes) to retrieve itself from the dictionary (meaning: `key` can only have the value "key" or `null`, since you are using `FirstOrDefault`). Then you are trying to lock by the value "key" (or `null`, which will throw an exception). There is no guarantee that the first "key" equals the "key" inside the dictionary; they could both be different references of the same value. The you are removing the "key" from the dictionary and then try to unlock. Why not call: `TryRemove(theKey)` to begin with?

Comment: The example is not actual implemented code but more a serial example of the order of events as I envisage them (which would happen in different threads). It was just really to demonstrate the issue I'm facing that I would potentially hit the exception 'Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.' Hence the need for the outer lock and the actual question.

Comment: Have you thought about a possibility to perform the updates on the dictionary in a single thread? Like making a single-thread scheduler and creating update tasks on this scheduler using `Task.Factory.StartNew` overload?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone, it seems that a previous comment was deleted that helped me find the answer, so I can't give credit where it is due.

I've implemented the ['ReaderWriterLockSlim' class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx). This allows multiple reader threads to process simultaneously, but only a single writer thread. So all processing threads take out a reader lock, but the thread that updates the dictionary takes out a writer lock. The writer lock waits for all reader locks to complete, but also takes priority over all reader locks. So once a writer lock is requested the reader locks must wait until the writer has completed before they can enter a critical section.

In addition to this, within the reader threads, I'm also applying a Monitor.TryLock to the actual object in the dictionary to prevent two threads processing the same item at the same time.